# Ability to freely transform KineticJS objects like FabricJS

Tags: transform, kineticjs, fabricjs

I love KineticJS, its speed, marriage with GSAP, but what is making my head spin is there a way to freely transform KineticJS objects like the way in FabricJS? Here is the link reference to what I am trying to say: http://fabricjs.com/customization/
I don't want to use FabricJs as its really slow, and its low performance evident from various unit tests.

I am really looking forward to finding a way to be able to freely transform object in KineticJS as it would make life so much easier.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks for your help,
Praney

Comment: Sure...start with this lab that illustrates how to resize an image using grabber-corners.  The same principles apply to user-resizing of most kinetic shapes:  http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/

Comment: My be helpfull: https://github.com/ghetolay/EdK

Comment: What exactly is slow in Fabric.js? We're always open to optimizations and suggestions.

Comment: @Lavrton Thanks mate, but it didn't work for me for some reason, I added the Kinetic.js reference but still I get a blank screen.

Comment: @kangax thanks mate,
Here is a small test I found : http://jsdo.it/djankey/test-fabricjs where performance can be compared. I have seen the Kinetic elements 10000 stress test and it works flawlessly.

Comment: @praneybehl I know that test (it's on http://fabricjs.com/particles/ too) and I get excellent speed on it in Chrome (almost at 60fps all the time). I'm still curious to see where Fabric is "really slow" :)

Comment: @kangax I tried the test again at http://fabricjs.com/particles/ hoping for a better performance but unfortunately, I don't get better than 18-29fps on Chrome Version 29.0.1547.66. I had nothing running on my system - (i5, 8GB Win8 Pro). I wonder how can I get higher performances :(

Comment: @Lavrton I got it working there was just typo while including library but the library appears to be a little buggy as it doesn't clear canvas if image is enlarged.

Comment: @praneybehl Very strange. I get 58 all the time on my Chrome 31 (Mac OS X 10.7.5, Core i7 MBP). I'll check it on Windows!

Comment: @kangax I am now convinced to give a thorough trial and I will get back with any issues. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like markE said, this [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/) on Eric's (creator of KineticJS) tutorial site is the basis for all free transforming within KineticJS.

I'll go into detail about the actual free transform logic, there are 2 main functions:

```
function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
  var stage = group.getStage();
  var layer = group.getLayer();

  //Create the anchor shape
  var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: x,
    y: y,
    stroke: '#666',
    fill: '#ddd',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    radius: 8,
    name: name,
    draggable: true,
    dragOnTop: false
  });

  //Calls the update function which handles the transform logic
  anchor.on('dragmove', function() {
    update(this);
    layer.draw();
  });
  //When the anchor is selected, we want to turn dragging off for the group
  //This is so that only the anchor is draggable, and we can transform instead of drag
  anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
    group.setDraggable(false);
    this.moveToTop();
  });
  //Turn back on draggable for the group
  anchor.on('dragend', function() {
    group.setDraggable(true);
    layer.draw();
  });
  // add hover styling
  anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
    var layer = this.getLayer();
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    this.setStrokeWidth(4);
    layer.draw();
  });
  anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
    var layer = this.getLayer();
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    this.setStrokeWidth(2);
    layer.draw();
  });

  group.add(anchor);
}
```

The `addAnchor` function, like the name says, adds a single anchor (or free transform handle) to a `Kinetic.Group`. By default it uses a `Kinetic.Circle` but really you can use any shape you want.

- `group` - the group to add the anchor to
- `x` - the x position of the anchor
- `y` - the y position of the anchor
- `name` - name of the anchor (usually describe which position the anchor represents, like **topLeft** or **bottomRight**

You'll notice a bunch of `events` attached to the newly created anchor, most of these are pretty straight-forward but the one you want to pay attention to is the `dragmove` event - this event is the one that calls the `update` function **which handles all the logic for transforming** the group/node. It's useful to note that the `update` function is called for every pixel that you are dragging an anchor.

The tutorial uses 4 corner anchors (thus calling addAnchor 4 times for each group/node), but if you wanted 8 anchors (4 corners - 4 sides) then you just have to adjust the logic to position the anchors correctly and to move the anchors properly when transforming.

By the way, **the reason we're adding Anchors to a Group**, is because we need them to group with the node in question, and stick with each node through dragging and transforming.

The second method is the `update` function:

```
function update(activeAnchor) {
  var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

  //Get each anchor inside the group, by name. Keep a standard set of names for every anchor you use and note they have to be names not ids because there will be multiple anchors named .topLeft in your app
  var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
  var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
  var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
  var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
  var image = group.get('.image')[0];

  var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
  var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();

  // update anchor positions
  switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
    case 'topLeft':
      //When topLeft is being dragged, topRight has to update in the Y-axis
      //And bottomLeft has to update in the X-axis
      topRight.setY(anchorY);
      bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
      break;
    case 'topRight':
      topLeft.setY(anchorY);
      bottomRight.setX(anchorX);
      break;
    case 'bottomRight':
      bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
      topRight.setX(anchorX); 
      break;
    case 'bottomLeft':
      bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
      topLeft.setX(anchorX); 
      break;
  }

  image.setPosition(topLeft.getPosition());

  //New height and width are calculated with a little math
  //by calculating the distance between the update anchor positions.
  var width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
  var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
  if(width && height) {
    image.setSize(width, height);
  }
}
```

The `update` function only takes one argument: the `activeAnchor` which is the anchor being dragged.

After that, it selects the other anchors within the group (using static names that you need to give each node and keep consistent throughout your app) so that we can translate their positions while the `activeAnchor` is being dragged.

The switch statement can get pretty large if you use 8 anchors instead of 4. This is because you need to consider translating almost all the other anchors while dragging one of them.

For an 8 anchor example: If you drag the `topLeft` anchor, you need to update the **y** position of the `topRight` anchor, the **x** position of the `bottomLeft` anchor, and for the `topMid` and `leftMid` anchors you need to adjust both the **x,y** values to stay in between the other anchors.

After updating the anchor position, the function handles the logic to resize the shape. Notice that the shape is selected by `var image = group.get('.image')[0];` But, what you can do is use the `get` function to select by type and do something like:

`var shape = group.get('Shape')[0];`

Obviously this will work best if you just have **1 shape per group** (to transform) + 4 or 8 anchors.

Let me know if you have any other questions or comments! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks alot mate, that is a very comprehensive explanation, I'll go through it and post back if I have questions. Really appreciate your time.
Thanks, Praney

Answer (score 0):

this project adds a transfrom tool (resize) and some nice handlers which can be used as a basis:
https://github.com/soloproyectos/jquery.transformtool

Comment: Thanks for the mention I did saw that before and created an issue that it is not compatible with the later kineticjs V5.x release.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please see my previous answer about this. just search my name. hope it will be a bid help for you :)  [Transform (Move/Scale/Rotate) shapes with KineticJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309306/transform-move-scale-rotate-shapes-with-kineticjs)

I forgot to include the html tags there so here it is... :)``

```
<!-- INSIDE THE HEAD TAGS -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- I am using jquery transform tool for kineticjs -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery.timer-1.0.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/kinetic-v4.7.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.transformtool-1.0.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                 //PUT THE JAVSCRIPT SNIPPET HERE FROM THE LINK THAT I PROVIDED ABOVE
</script>
```

//THE ADD div element with id = canvas and file element with id = files and name files[] INSIDE THE BODY