# Resizable rectangle using mouse/finger

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I'm trying to make tool, with which help you can select objects available in KineticJS stage, i'm currently stuck at making resizable rectangle, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/EvKpA/2/ here is what i've made so far. 
`I want to make that rectangle resizable, while dragging rectResize.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/) on creating anchors to free transform shapes/images in KineticJS.

To make it available to touch, you'll have to add the `touchmove` event with the `dragmove` event.

Check out this thread for a detailed explanation: [Ability to freely transform KineticJS objects like FabricJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777524/ability-to-freely-transform-kineticjs-objects-like-fabricjs/18788380#18788380)